# Does not working Start-Overlay-in-Application-View

Tags: gnome

I have installed Start-Overlay-in-Application-View on a notebook from:
https://github.com/Hexcz/Start-Overlay-in-Application-View-for-Gnome-40-

But when I press super key nothing happend.

OS information:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64
GNOME Shell 42.5

What could I check?

[User extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhATq.png)

Comment: @guiverc I've said that I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 Is it not version/release?